# MA3B3 isomers - is this same as meridional one?

Tags: stereochemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

I'm new to studying stereo chemistry. (Now I'm studying coordination complexes.)

In my class material and other some datas(from google), it says that there is two, fac and mer.
I want to know is whether the image is meridional one.
By the explanation, two A-M-A bond angles are 90 degrees, and the other is 180 degrees - so I guess it is the mer one.
Or not, I want to know why it is not possible, or not stable.

(I'm guessing my picture is the less stable version.)
[image]
I'm looking forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: Yes, mer, that's him all right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Is there not some energy issue?

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: @IvanNeretin like stablity

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: @IvanNeretin ah, in my materials, there was a picture for mer isomer that one a is on top side, and others in horizonal side.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So I was wondering if my picture's case is unstable than the material's case.

Comment: You realize that there is no top side in the real world, don't you?

Comment: @IvanNeretin ah. In my country it's 2 am. I was almost sleeping. Thank you for answering kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of: *In my class material and other some data (from google), it says that there is two, fac and mer,* is somewhat misleading. These two type of isomers are only possible in $\ce{MA3B3}$ type of complexes (*e.g.*, $\ce{[Co(NH3)3(NO2)3]}$):

[image: Geometrical facial and meridonal isomers]

1. In *facial* isomer (*fac*-), all three same type of ligands have $90^\circ$ $\ce{A-M-A}$ angles (same is for all three $\ce{B-M-B}$ angles). As shown in following diagram, all three of same types of ligands are clustered in one side of the octahedron so that they looks like the base of a triogonal pyramid (shown as red triangle on $\ce{NO2}$), head of which is the metal itself. The three other kind of ligands are on the opposite side of the  octahedron, arranged in similar manner.
2. In *meridional* isomer (*mer*-), all the three ligands of same type are arranged in a T-shape in same plane including the metal such that there are two $90^\circ$ $\ce{A-M-A}$ angles and one $180^\circ$ $\ce{A-M-A}$ angles, making it 'T' with metal in the middle (same is true for $\ce{B-M-B}$ angles, though on the opposite side). Also keep in mind that $\ce{A-M(A)-A}$ plane is perpendicular to $\ce{B-M(B)-B}$ plane.

Also note that neither is optically active since both have plane of symmetry. For *mer*-isomer, both $\ce{A-M(A)-A}$ and $\ce{B-M(B)-B}$ planes are planes of symmetry. For *fac*-isomer, for example, the plane (indicated by dotted line in the figure) going through *trans*-$(\ce{A-M-B})$ axis, dividing the octahedron to two is a plane of symmetry.

According to above description, your drown structure is *mer*-isomer (see red dotted lines for T-shape with $\ce{A}$ and blue dotted lines for T-shape with $\ce{B}$), which you have realized after discussion with Ivan Neretin.